# Probability of the distance between two noisy measurements being less than a threshold.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, signal-processing, noise

Imagine we have two signals:

$ x_1[t]=\hat{x}_1[t]+N(0, \Sigma_1)$

$ x_2[t]=\hat{x}_2[t]+N(0, \Sigma_2)$

Where $x_i,~\hat{x}_i $ are the measured, true values, respectively, and $ N(0, \Sigma_i)$ is a Gaussian noise. The true values are changing over time and they are not following any specific type of distributions, however, we know that the signals are continuous. Given $T_k$ observations (which can be large) over time, I am wondering if there is any way to calculate the following probability:

$P(\|\hat{x}_1[t]-\hat{x}_2[t]\|<\delta,\mu,\Sigma)$

where $\mu=\frac{ \sum\limits_{i=0}^{T_k}\|{x}_1[t-i]-{x}_2[t-i]\|}{T_k}$ and $\Sigma=var(\|{x}_1[t-i]-{x}_2[t-i]\|)$ are the mean and the variance of $T_k$ observations.
Any suggestion?

Comment: A follow-up comment
For example, is it safe to assume that $ P(\|(\hat{x}_1[t]−\hat{x}_2[t]\|<δ,μ,Σ)=N(\|\hat{x}_1[t]−\hat{x}_2[t]\|<δ=μ,Σ)$ where N is a normal distribution?